# Creating a function and calling it on another file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this checking auth function on my `login.js` page, inside my `routes` folder. my dir is set up like so:

```
routes
    login.js

views
    index.ejs
    login.ejs

app.js
```

so I have a function inside `app.js` like this:

```
app.get('/dashboard', auth, (req, res) => {
     ...

})
```

the `auth` function inside the `login.js` looks like this:

```
    function auth(res, req, next) {
    if (req.session.loggedin) {
        return next();
    } else {
      req.session.destory;
      res.redirect('/login')
    }
}

module.exports = app
```

here's how I am requiring the code inside the login page:

```
var login = require('./routes/login')
app.use(login)
```

However, when I require the proper file name and everything, it says auth is not recognized. how is this possible? How do I fix this?

Comment: why don't you show us how you "require the proper file name and everything"? your export statement looks wrong already. You are not exporting auth it seems.

Comment: I'm agree with @ChristianFritz, need to `exports` `auth`

Comment: @ChristianFritz I've just added how I require the file to the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `login.js` file, you have written `module.exports = app`. Instead, You have to write `module.exports = auth` to send the auth function.

So, when you `var login = require('./routes/login')`, you get the function `auth()` from `login.js` and store the function in the name `login` in `app.js`

Therefore, while reffering in `app.js`, your function is `login()` and not `auth()` as you imported it that way.

If you want to use `auth` in `app.js` you can do `var auth = require('./routes/login');`

Otherwise instead of writing `app.get('dashboard', auth ...` you have to write `app.get('dashboard', login ...`

Comment: Moreover, you may not add `(req, res)` after `auth` as you can perform all operations inside the `login.js` file itself for get requests of `'dashboard'`

Comment: Welcome @Gianluca